# How to integrate AndroidManifest.xml?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, manifest

So I need to integrate unity with android feature like connect to 3rd party app.

So I made .apk build after working at eclipse, but how to integrate between 2 AndroidManifest files?

First reference one is,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.mygame.plugin"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

          <intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="ka67492508561297" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
          </intent-filter>                   
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.kakao.unity.plugin.ThirdPartyPostStoryActivity" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"/>
</application> 
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
```

and the main one my game currently uses is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.mygame.mygame1"
android:installLocation="preferExternal"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
android:versionCode="2"
android:versionName="1.01">
<supports-screens
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true"/>
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

          <intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="ka7492508561297" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
          </intent-filter>                   
    </activity>

      <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerProxyActivity"
              android:launchMode="singleTask"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen"> 

        <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="true" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity"
              android:launchMode="singleTask"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity"
              android:launchMode="singleTask"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen">            
            <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="true" />
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="org.onepf.openiab.UnityProxyActivity"
              android:launchMode="singleTask"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen">
    </activity>
     <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
          android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.ka.unity.plugin.ThirdPartyPostStoryActivity" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"/>
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="com.sec.android.iap.permission.BILLING"/>
<uses-permission android:name="org.onepf.openiab.permission.BILLING"/>
```

So I merged reference one to my main one like above, 
But error says,

[UnityException: Unable to start activity!
No activity in the manifest with action MAIN and category LAUNCHER. Try launching the application manually on the device.]

I still can make .apk file, and can run on my phone, but can't connect to 3rd party app when in-game button touched that should launch connection.

So strange... how should I fix?

Thanks.